# Extending is_arithmetic struct for custom type

Tags: c++, eigen

I was looking into improving TensorPadding operator for tensorflow's bfloat16 type, and I found that TensorExecutor does not use Tiled version for bfloat16 operations. On more investigation, I found that one solution would be to specify:

```
template <>
struct is_arithmetic<tensorflow::bfloat16> { enum { value = true }; };
```

And enable BlockAccessV2 in `TensorPadding.h`. But

```
template <typename T> struct is_arithmetic { enum { value = false }; };
```

is already defined in `Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h`, and does not allow defining this function for custom types.

Any thoughts on how one may define this function? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: I don't get your problem. The second code snippet is a template. (Strictly speaking, it's a class template but not a function template.) The first snippet is a template specialization. This should work in general as this is how it is supposed to be used. The only issue I could imagine: specialization may not work without previous template definition. You didn't forget to `#include <Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h>` prior the definition of `template <>
struct is_arithmetic<tensorflow::bfloat16>`?

Comment: I would make this an answer but I'm not quite sure whether I'm on the right track. I made this [mcve on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d5eaa91546ac4b) for illustration. If you change `#if 1` to `#if 0` (to exclude the template definition) this doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: Except all files under `Eigen/src/` are internal implementation of Eigen and should not be included.

Comment: Thanks @Scheff for input. If I try to implement specialization for bfloat16 in a separate file, I get multiple definitions error, with is_struct<T> being first definition. Meta.h gets included in the file where I am trying to add is_struct<bfloat16> specialization.

Comment: `is_struct`? Aren't we talking anymore about `is_arithmetic`?

Comment: Concerning multiple definitions error: Maybe, there already is a specialization `template <> struct is_arithmetic<tensorflow::bfloat16>`.

Comment: Please, [edit] and copy/paste the exact error messages. A [mcve] wouldn't be bad as well.